# Handlebars in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, handlebars.js

I need to use Handlebars inside of a jsp page. I have handlebars-v1.3.0.js in my js folder and used the following code snippet to include that js file into my jsp page.

## code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
```

I tried `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>` also. But no luck.

But when the page is loaded I am getting an error "Hanldebars not defined" in my browser console. Please suggest what am I doing wrong.The whole thing is working if I use handlebars inside of an html page.

Folder structure is as shown below.

```
-WebContent
  --Home.jsp

-js
  --handlebars-v1.3.0.js
```

I would like to know two things.
 1.) what is the right way to give the js file path inside the jsp file ?
 2.) Does jsp support handlebars ?

'components' is an array object which is defined in another js.

## My source code(Home.jsp) :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My first JSP</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Handlebars.registerHelper('eachByIdx', function(menuData, options) {

            // My Logic 
    });

    var menuSource = document.getElementById("myTemplate").innerHTML;
    var menuTemplate = Handlebars.compile(menuSource);
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = menuTemplate(menuData);
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <form action="Hello" method="post">
            <input type="text" value="ajith" />
        <script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <table>

       {{#eachByIdx components}}
                    // My Logic here              
       {{/eachByIdx}}

        <tr>
            <td>
             <a href="" onclick="return popup(this.form)">Add New</a>                   
     </td>
        </tr>           
        </table>       
       </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a relative path to load JS files from within JSP files, since JSP files can be:

- Located essentially anywhere, and
- May be used (e.g., included) in other places

Instead, use an absolute path relative to your web content root, ideally using a JSP URL-ish tag so the context is provided automatically.

Comment: @ Dave: 
I tried the absolute path as well as shown below. But no luck. 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
Can u please give me sample code for URL-ish tag. I am pretty new into this jsp and all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding absolute path , try ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/handlebars-v1.3.0.js
2. Yes , please move your scripts code to the bottom, you are trying use getElementById , but the page did not finish loading.

Please see below sample:

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
> <script   src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>     <form action="Hello" method="post">
>         <input type="text" value="ajith" />
>       <div id="div1"></div>
>     </form>
>
> <script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
>   <table>
>       {{#eachByIdx components}}
>                   // My Logic here
>       {{/eachByIdx}}
>       <tr>
>           <td>
>            <a href="" onclick="return popup(this.form)">Add New</a>
>           </td>
>       </tr>           
>   </table>       
> </script> 
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     Handlebars.registerHelper('eachByIdx', function(menuData, options) {
>             //My Logic 
>     });
>
>     var menuSource = document.getElementById("myTemplate").innerHTML;
>     var menuTemplate = Handlebars.compile(menuSource);
>     document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = menuTemplate(menuTemplate);
> </script> 
> </body>
> </html>
> ```